# Multiple Bindings to a GridView DataSource

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind three queries to a GridView DataSource. From my understanding you can't bind more then one query to a GridView DataSource, Is this true? Is so, how would you go about taking multiple queries and binding them to one GridView. For example:

```
var query1 = select * from table 1
var query2 = select * from table 2
var query3 = select * from table 3


GridView.DataSource = query1;
GridView.DataSource = query2;
GridView.DataSource  = query3;
```

This is basically what I want to do, but from what I can find this is possible. Is there a good way to do something like this? Thanks!

So, basically I have multiple queries and I need certain results from all of them to go into one GridView.

Comment: is all these tables with same structure? if then try one query with UNION to return all data

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want join of queries or concatenation of it or something else?

Comment: Different structures. Basically I have multiple queries and I need certain results from all of them to go into one GridView.

Answer (score 0):

From [DataGridView.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)

> The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms
>   data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that
>   implements one of the following interfaces:
>
> 1. The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
> 2. The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet
>      classes.
> 3. The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList class.
> 4. The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.

You might want to rather bind a `DataSet` then

Answer (score 0):

If all of the queries are of the same type then you can combine them into a single collection before binding them to the gridview:

```
var aggregateQuery = query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3);
GridView.DataSource = aggregateQuery;
```

If the queries are not of the same type then you either need to do something to convert them into a single common schema (we'd need to know more to provide details) or you would need to have 3 separate grid views and only bind one to each query.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you cannot do multi bindings.

However, you can concatenate the query to bring in ALL the records into a single DataTable and then bind to it.

ie

Assuming `<asp:SqlDataSource...` where your SELECT has the entire data in a single query

```
        DataSourceSelectArguments dss = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        SqlDataSource sds = (SqlDataSource)YourControl.FindControl("your datasource control");
        if (sds != null)
        {
            DataView dv = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            if (dv != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)dv.ToTable();
                if (dt != null)
                {
                  myGridView.DataSource = dt;
                  myGridView.DataSourceID = null; //won't be needed
                  myGridView.DataBind();
etc
```